# database connectivity in war file

Tags: jsp, tomcat

i have done a web application project in jsp.
For that i have created a war file and deployed it on another machine in eclipse.i have restore the database on that machine also.it runs on browser when i gave path of first jsp page.But now problem is that in my jsp page username and password for connecting to database is differnt.so it gives error when trying to run on different machine.
So what changes are required so that it will run on different machine as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have to unjar war file and change username and password inside the XML.

Comment: But user will not have any idea how & where to make changes?

Comment: But there is no other way to do it(:

Comment: So can't we place a war file having connectivity code (to sql server 2005)on different machine?

Comment: u can place it but u have to change username and password inside the jar file every time when there is a change

Comment: Is your username and password is hard coded inside the java code or defined in XML(web.xml) file??????????????????????

Comment: Yes it is hard coded.I dont know how to define it in web.xml. Can we do that in web.xml?

Comment: So now there is no way to change it. You have to change it inside the source code,recomile it,creating the new jar and then redeploy to webserver.

Comment: but it is not reliable solution,what if we want to distribute it to multiple clients..

Comment: U can use properties file with key value pairs of username and password

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it.can u plz explain in detail

Comment: You can read tutorial on  http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/Properties/properties-file.shtml

Comment: ok thanx.so now i create the text file which has.properties extention,m i correct?and where can i put this file?